# Showing $\ell^1$ is not Hilbertable.

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following information.

> A Banach space $X$ is said to be **Hilbertable** provided there is an inner product on $X$ whose induced norm is equivalent to the given norm.

> A Banach space $X$ is said to be complemented provided every closed subspace of $X$ has a closed linear complement.  A Banach space is complemented iff it is Hilbertable.

I know that $\ell^1$ is not innerproduct space under sum of componentwise product as it does not satisfy parallelogram identity. But doing this looks silly as it induces $\ell^2$ norm. I know that $\ell^1$ is separable and its dual space $\ell^\infty$ is not separable. Which approach would be best to show that $\ell^1$ is not Hilbertable?

Note, this is exercise from Royden 16.2.

Comment: Does Royden really write *hilbertable*? I have only seen *hilbertizable*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that $\ell^1$ is separable and its dual space $\ell^\infty$ is not separable.

This is what you need!

**Fact** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Then $H$ is conjugate-isomorphic to its dual -- in particular, it is homeomorphic to its dual.

I'll leave the proof to you.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with Riesz-Frechet Representation Theorem?

Comment: It absolutely does. To show that $H$ is conjugate-isomorphic to its dual, you will need to construct a conjugate-linear bijective isometry $H \to H^*$. How would you try to do this?

Comment: I think I can do it.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that we are using $\ell^1 \cong H$ as Banach spaces implies $(\ell^1) \cong H^*$ which would imply $$ \ell^1 \cong H \cong H^* \cong (\ell^1)^* $$ yielding a contradiction. It is not difficult, but also not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the following facts:

- Boundedness of sequences is invariant under going to an equivalent norm.
- Weak convergence of sequences is invariant under going to an equivalent norm.
- Bounded sequences in Hilbert spaces have weakly convergent subsequences.
- In $\ell^1$ there are bounded sequences without weakly convergent subsequences.